# ¿Cómo direccionar por rol, mostrar saludo, así como enviar datos en request? PDO, AJAX y JWT

Tags: php, ajax, pdo, jwt

Contexto: Tengo un problema con $session de PHP, a cada rato truena la sesión provocando que los usuarios del sistema tengan que loguearse a cada rato o dejan a medias algunas peticiones AJAX. Entonces me comentaron que puedo usar JWT para evitar eso, estoy apenas entendiendo como funcionan los JWT, les muestro mi código para que revisen un poco.

AJAX Request:

```
function accessSystem(usuario, contrasenia) { // credenciales del usuario "usuario" y "contraseña"
    $.ajax({
        url: '../model/login_sesion.php',
        data: {
            usuario_acceso: usuario,
            contrasenia_acceso: contrasenia
        },
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        beforeSend: () => {
            console.log('Enviando petición');
        }
    }).done( (response) => {
        // Aquí recibo y proceso el token (response.token)
    }).always( (response) => {
        console.log('Se completo la petición');
    }).fail((jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) => {
        console.log(`Tenemos un problema ${jqXHR.status} al brindarte acceso al sistema`);
    });
}
```

Login.php

```
require('../database/db_config.php');
require('../model/response.php');
require('../vendor/autoload.php');

use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;

$conexionServidor = new ConexionServidor('usuarios');
$responseLogin = new ResponseLogin();
$conexionBaseDatos = $conexionServidor->conexionBaseDatos();

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    if (!$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
        $responseLogin->estado = false;
        $responseLogin->mensajeEstado = 'Método de solicitud incorrecto';
        $responseLogin->tipoRol = '';
        echo json_encode($responseLogin);
        return;
    }

    $usuarioAcceso = $_POST['usuario_acceso'];
    $contraseniaAcceso = $_POST['contrasenia_acceso'];

    $sentenciaPreparada = null;

    try {
        $sentenciaPreparada = $conexionBaseDatos->prepare(
            "SELECT nombre, usuario, contrasenia, id_cargo FROM bujic_usuariosbj.usuarios WHERE BINARY usuario = :usernameAcceso AND BINARY contrasenia = :passwordAcesso LIMIT 1"
        );
        $sentenciaPreparada->bindValue(':usernameAcceso', $usuarioAcceso, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sentenciaPreparada->bindValue(':passwordAcesso', $contraseniaAcceso, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $sentenciaPreparada->execute();

        $numeroFilas = $sentenciaPreparada->rowCount();

        if ($numeroFilas <= 0) {
            $responseLogin->estado = false;
            $responseLogin->mensajeEstado = 'Usuario no registrado en BUJICNET';
            $responseLogin->tipoRol = '';
            echo json_encode($responseLogin);
            return;
        }

        $fila = $sentenciaPreparada->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $payload = array(
            'usuario' => $fila['usuario'],
            'nombre_usuario' => $fila['nombre'],
            'rol_usuario' => $fila['id_cargo'],
        );

        static $ALGORITMO = 'HS256';
        $secretKey =  bin2hex(random_bytes(32));

        $token = JWT::encode($payload, $secretKey, $ALGORITMO);

        $responseLogin->estado = true;
        $responseLogin->mensajeEstado = 'Iniciando sesión, espere...';
        $responseLogin->tokenJWT = $token;
        echo json_encode($responseLogin);
        
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $mensajeError = $e->getMessage();
        echo $mensajeError;
    } finally {
        if ($sentenciaPreparada && $sentenciaPreparada !== null) {
            $sentenciaPreparada->closeCursor();
        }
    }
}
```

Todo funciona bien, ** echo json_encode($responseLogin);** hace bien su trabajo, manda lo que debe mandar como response a AJAX, mis dudas son

1. ¿Cómo le hago para redireccionar a cada página según su rol?
   Rol agente -> Pantalla de Operaciones
   Rol gerencia -> Pantalla de Gerencias
   ... así sucesivamente

   Entiendo que esa información se manda en el $payload del token desde PHP, información como "tipo_rol", "nombre_usuario", información no sensible, si no para personalizar la experiencia del usuario, pero como hago eso de redireccionar, ¿Descifro el token? Como lo siguiente, dentro del success de AJAX:

   const DECODE_TOKEN = parseJwt(response.tokenJWT);
   localStorage.setItem('user_data', JSON.stringify(DECODE_TOKEN));

   if (DECODE_TOKEN.rol_usuario === 2) {
   location.href = 'operaciones.php';
   } else if (response.rol_usuario === 1) {
   location.href = 'gerencias.php';
   }
2. ¿Sí quiero mostrar por el ejemplo el nombre_usuario en otra parte del sitio web?
   Guardo el DECODE_TOKEN.nombre_usuario en localStorage y luego usarlo con getItem
3. La pregunta 2 también va porque por ejemplo en el sistema se hacen INSERTS a una tabla y esa tabla tiene una columna para guardar quién generea el insert, entonces en la data de la AJAX request debo colocar data {empleado: getItem('DECODE_TOKEN.nombre_usuario')}.
   Actualemente el sistema hace eso pero con sesiones de PHP $Session['usuario_nombre']; y lo guarda en una variable
4. No creo que sea seguro guardar esa información en LocalStorage, puede que desde console modifique esa información y en el inserte se pierda la integridad de realmente sea el nombre de un empleado, a menos que en el backend haga una validación a una tabla catalogo ¿Es buena practica?

Reitero, apenas estoy viendo esto de JWT, no se si sea practico mover de sessiones a JWT, según sí pero bueno aquí ando molestandolos un poco con esto.

Comment: Tu pregunta tiene tres problemas: 1. Es demasiado larga. Parecería que estás preguntando cuatro cosas. El sitio exige una pregunta por problema. 2. No es clara. ¿Cuál es el problema en concreto? ¿En qué parte del código? ¿Qué pruebas has hecho y con qué resultados? ¿Qué obtienes y qué esperas obtener? ¿Qué errores tienes? 3. Está basada en opiniones: *cómo le hago para*, *creo que es mejor tal cosa*, etc. Sugiero que pulses en [edit] y que nos digas cuál es el problema, partiendo de lo que estás implementando y de las pruebas que has hecho.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque: 1. No es clara. 2. Es demasiado larga. 3. Está basada en opiniones, no en un problema concreto.

Comment: 1. Es demasiada larga, luego no pongo código y como quiera la cierran 2. Si es clara, presta atención y lee detenidamente 3. No son opiniones externas, son mis dudas, estuve investigando...

Comment: Mi problema es que ya mando el token en la responde, lo recibo correctamente, en el token va el payload, que contiene "nombre de usuario" y "rol de usuario", entonces para redirigir a otra pagina en base al rol ¿Descifro el token? ¿Cómo se le hace para mantener la sesión activa? ¿En caso de generar insertes, con información del payload, guardo en local storage y luego por data de la petición AJAX obtengo el Item del local Storage?